# Monit and amavis

Tags: monit, amavis

I have noticed that occasionally amavis is not running.

I thought monit was watching the process, however it doesn't seem to warn me or fix it.

My monitrc entry looks like this and I can confirm that starting/stopping the process with monit works:

```
check process amavisd with pidfile /var/run/amavis/amavisd.pid
     group mail
     start program = "/etc/init.d/amavis start"
     stop  program = "/etc/init.d/amavis stop"
     if failed port 10024 protocol smtp then restart
     if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
     depends on amavisd_bin
     depends on amavisd_rc

   check file amavisd_bin with path /usr/sbin/amavisd-new
     group mail
     if failed checksum then unmonitor
     if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
     if failed uid root then unmonitor
     if failed gid root then unmonitor

   check file amavisd_rc with path /etc/init.d/amavis
     group mail
     if failed checksum then unmonitor
     if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
     if failed uid root then unmonitor
     if failed gid root then unmonitor
```

How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Process 'sshd'                      Not monitored
Process 'mysql'                     Not monitored
Process 'postfix'                   Not monitored
Process 'amavisd'                   Connection failed
File 'amavisd_bin'                  Accessible
File 'amavisd_rc'                   Accessible
Process 'clamd'                     Not monitored
Process 'dovecot'                   Not monitored
File 'dovecot_init'                 Accessible
File 'dovecot_bin'                  Accessible

Comment: looks like I have some work to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct pidfile path is `/var/run/amavisd/amavisd.pid`

so you are missing a '`d`' in '`amavisd`' directory name.

Start and Stop would work since start/stop paths are ok but pid file won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking that all the tests in the monit configuration is valid.

- Does the configuration file have valid syntax?
- Does `/var/run/amavis/amavisd.pid` exist?
- Does `/etc/init.d/amavis` start and stop functions work?
- Is amavis listening on port 10024 protocol SMTP?
- Does `/usr/sbin/amavisd-new` and `/etc/init.d/amavis` exists?

Then you should continue to check the output of `monit summary` and `monit status verbose` and check if the output will help you to find the problem.

This might be a problem with monit or a problem with amavis. Or a combination of both. If you post more information (e.g. output from `monit summary`) I will edit this answer with more help.

Comment: I have checked through each of those and the answer is yes. I mentioned I can start it with monit, and monit warns me when it goes down: Connection failed Service amavisd

        Date:        Thu, 19 Dec 2013 13:26:22
        Action:      restart
        Host:        myserver.com.au
        Description: failed protocol test [SMTP] at INET[localhost:10024] via TCP -- SMTP: error receiving data -- Resource temporarily unavailable